# Taking a subset of rows of full column rank matrix so it becomes square, what happens to rank (and invertibility)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $L$ be a $p\times r $ matrix with $r < p$ such that $\text{rk}\, L = r$. If I take the last $r$ rows by carrying out the following:

$\left[ 0 \, \vdots \, I_{r} \right ]\, L = L_{r}$ where $L_r$ is now an $r \times r$ matrix, am I correct in concluding that the $\text{rk}\, L_r = r$ so that $L_r$ becomes invertible? If so, how could I prove this?

All help is warmly appreciated!

Comment: Taking a subset of rows cannot *increase* the rank of a matrix, but it might *decrease* the rank.  Think a bit more about possible counterexamples to your conclusion.

Comment: It's at most $r$. You could probably make a small example of an $p \times r $ matrix where choosing $r$ rows won't do this